# React components can't load an image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react component that loads user profile including image but when I used the component in different pages, the images doesn't load properly.

```
<img src="img/usr.jpg" alt="user">
```

when I looked in the "inspect"

`in the '/' page the image url is '/img/usr.jpg'`

in the search page

`the image url is "/search/img/usr.jpg"`

I want to keep the image url the same regardless of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative path which will look for the image in the current url

To use an absolute path prefix it with '/'

so instead of this

```
<img src="img/usr.jpg" alt="user">
```

use this

```
<img src="/img/usr.jpg" alt="user">
```